# html template returns text instead of html

Tags: go

I've the below code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    htmlTempl "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

var templatesHtml *htmlTempl.Template
var err error

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Starting up.")
    templatesHtml = htmlTempl.Must(htmlTempl.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
}

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err = templatesHtml.ExecuteTemplate(w, "other.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8080",
    }
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/test", test)
    server.ListenAndServe()
}
```

And my templates are:

```html
// Content of base.html:
{{define "base"}}
<html>
  <head>{{template "head" .}}</head>
  <body>{{template "body" .}}</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

And

```html
// Content of other.html:
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "head"}}<title>other</title>{{end}}
{{define "body"}}other{{end}}
```

The output I got at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test` is:

[image]

While I was expecting normal HTML page to be displayed!

Comment: `//` Are not comment markers in template files, as you seem to think. Check the docs for how to write comments in templates. Or just drop the comment, it's not really adding any value, is it? Another alternative, if you have to keep the `//` thing in the file, wrap the html content of the other.html file in it's own `define` action, just like you did with base.html, just make sure you then pass the correct name of the resulting template to the ExecuteTemplate method.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, it worked by removing the `/` or commenting them by `<!-- -->`, using `define` gave the error `panic: template: other.html:5: unexpected <define> in command`

Comment: I assume you put it someplace wrong, or used the wrong syntax, there's no reason a third valid `define` (note you already have two in that file), should suddenly start failing. It's not like there is a limit in how many defines a template file can have. Without seeing the updated file however I can be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments provided by [mkoprivs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) the error was in using `//` as comment markers, it had be solved by replacing them with the html content comment marker as below:

```
<!-- Content of other.html: -->
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "head"}}<title>other</title>{{end}}
{{define "body"}}other{{end}}
```

And it is working fine now.